# What is the simplest possible circuit for a wireless on-off switch

Tags: wireless

On one side I have 5V DC powering an LED, and on the other side I have a button (switch/latch/whatever). What's the simplest circuit for this button to control the state of the LED (hopefully without OpAmps)? Range is not important, just the principle. Not including electromagnetic induction...

Comment: Is IR allowed? There are very simple detectors which just detect the presence of an IR carrier signal.

Comment: @mkeith, yeah sure.

Comment: I just re-read your question. Is the switch on the same board as the LED? If so you can use an opto-coupler IC to keep them totally electrically separate. This would basically be a photo-transistor and an LED inside a single package.

Comment: Google TSOP38238 from Vishay. When it detects the carrier, it sets the output low. When the carrier is absent, the output is high.

Comment: LED to photo transistor, LDR, light sensor, ... . Sound - audible with transducers (speaker/beeper/mic ...) , ultrasonic. Piezo or other vibration. Capacitive coupling. Small RF modules for maybe $2-$4. SAW oscillator TX, regen/super-egen RX. |Spin a magnet (alternator). Electrostatic.  ...

Comment: No op-amps and no EM induction and presumably, by inference, no radio because EM induction is one half of a radio wave when using a loop antenna or, taken further no inductors at all - this pretty much excludes any radio receiver. Without justification for these strange requirements this question is really inadequate.

Comment: @Andyaka, by "no induction" I actually meant being the only power supplier ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V0yRJspOyA)). So RF/IR signal is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way I know is using light, put a phototransistor into the circuit as a low-side switch and shine a light at it, it will turn your LED on. This is good within line of sight. You can make this a fun laser tagging game my shielding the phototransistor so only a head on laser beam would hit it.

If you have to use radio waves within a short range, you can look into `TA7642`-based AM receiver and a single transistor AM transmitter. Feed the output of `TA7642` into a Schmitt trigger and control a MOSFET with the output of it. This is good within up to a few tens of meters, about covering your house and maybe include your neighbor in the range. If you have some elderly living within that range this can be a very Good Samaritan project.

For even wider coverage range, you may be better off using Wi-Fi or 3G and control your trinket using Internet.